# Creating a Migration for Mikro-Orm

Tags: mikro-orm

I'm currently trying to a create a new migration in my project after the initial one. I started with a script and although it's running throughout with no errors, the actual job didn't go through.

`yarn mikro-orm migration:create`

I decided to turn my script off and use the above CLI to get it working, and it still hasn't created but has continuously given my an output of...

`No changes required, schema is up-to-date`

I've already ran through an update on my schema to check if anything was wrong but there were no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens when you run migration:up?

I recommend experimenting with these commands:

```
npx mikro-orm migration:up       # Migrate up to the latest version
npx mikro-orm migration:down     # Migrate one step down
npx mikro-orm migration:list     # List all executed migrations
npx mikro-orm migration:pending  # List all pending migrations
```

Comment: Although I'm not working on the project anymore (I gave up and tried a different approach), this could have worked. I didn't know about these commands existing when I first tried. Not a guarantee but it's better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggled for a while before I can come up with this.

1. If you are working on Typescript, check if your mikro-orm config look up entities in JS or TS. I have tried several times for having updated the TS files, forgetting to build the JS files but run `mikro-orm migration:create` directly. It makes the CLI checking on the unchanged JS files and response 'no changes' required.
2. Besides of above, I also find clearing the mikro-orm cache, and generate new cache helps me to ensure I am in a freshly-new state.

In summary, my not-so-smart steps are:

```
yarn build // or the build command of your project
npx mikro-orm cache:clear // clear all cache
npx mikro-orm cache:generate // re-generate JS cache...
npx mikro-orm cache:generate --ts // ...or re-generate TS cache
npx mikro-orm migration:create
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by removing the `.snapshot-test-migration.json` under the `migrations` folder.